# Can't create a psycho?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have all of the DLC to date. However, I can not create a Psycho. I have right clicked BL2 in steam and made sure the Ultimate Vault Hunter pack was installed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you really think that gearbox is giving you a new playable character for free without ripping you off?^^

Comment: @user28015 They did with Gaige, albeit with a Season Pass. But right, Krieg is not included into Season Pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Psycho pack launches in May. read this: http://www.gamespot.com/news/borderlands-2-adds-psycho-pack-in-may-6405856

Comment: Wait... So how is everyone from Reddit discovering Psycho Class mods?

Comment: Maybe a mistake in the loot tables.

Comment: It could be that they just want players to be able to gear up their psycho before the DLC launches

Comment: And create hype, I bet. My level 12 commando has found Psycho gear in vending machines already.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Its probably Gearbox trying to be "sneaky" and add in his lootables before his release in about a week and a half. I'm willing to bet he releases the same day as PokerNight 2 or Farcry3 Blood Dragon because usually Microsoft adds fairly popular stuff together on the marketplace. And people have found out about every dlc because of files in updates. Its either Gearbox being lazy about updates, or really bad at sneaking in the new gear. Same thing happened with the Mechromancer class mods I believe. I imagine since this has been realized within the last few days we will most likely get an official release date in the next few days.

Comment: What does Microsoft have to do with anything?